# Delete messages of a banned user?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot for discord in discord.js, but I would like to delete all the message (especially the stock welcome messages). What should I do to delete all the messages by a user and mentioning the user (without knowing the room of the stock messages)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<GuildMember>.ban(7)` will ban the member and delete the last 7 days worth of messages. This includes the welcome message if it was sent in the last 7 days.

### *Other `.ban()` arguments*

`<GuildMember>.ban('ban reason')` will add a ban reason

If you want both message deletion and a reason, create an object.

```
let options = {
    days: 7
    reason: 'ban reason'
}

<GuildMember>.ban(options);
```